# Convert CSV to RDD and read with Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, rdd

I tried to read a file (csv) and print its schema. My problem is that my file has not header to query like SQL.
I tried with this code:

```
val logFile = "../resouces/cells.csv"

val dfCells = spark.read
 .format("csv")
 .option("header", "false")
 .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
 .option("delimiter", "|")
 .csv(logFile)

dfCell.printSchema;
```

The file input is:

```
ES|15032017|25100|54600||3G|FIBRE|OUTDOOR|COMPANY|MAST|MACRO||47001|DU|41.651834|-4.728534||||||||||||||||
ES|15032017|25101|54601||3G|FIBRE|OUTDOOR|COMPANY|ROOFTOP|MACRO||47001|DU|41.651994|-4.724693||||||||||||||||
ES|15032017|25102|54602||4G|FIBRE|OUTDOOR|COMPANY|ROOFTOP|MICRO||47001|U|41.650912|-4.720648||||||||||||||||
ES|15032017|25103|54603||3G|MICROWAVES|OUTDOOR|COMPANY|ROOFTOP|MACRO||47001|U|41.647312|-4.717118||||||||||||||||
```

The output is:

```
|
|
|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo. Use `dfCells.printSchema`.

Answer (score 0):

I use Spark 1.5.0 with `load` function instead of `csv`.

```
val logFile = "../input.csv"

val dfCells = sqlContext.read
                        .format("csv")
                        .option("header", "false")
                        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
                        .option("delimiter", "|")
                        .load(logFile)

dfCells.show()
+---+--------+-----+-----+---+---+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----+---+-----+---+---------+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| C0|      C1|   C2|   C3| C4| C5|        C6|     C7|     C8|     C9|  C10|C11|  C12|C13|      C14|      C15|C16|C17|C18|C19|C20|C21|C22|C23|C24|C25|C26|C27|C28|C29|C30|C31|
+---+--------+-----+-----+---+---+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----+---+-----+---+---------+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ES|15032017|25100|54600|   | 3G|     FIBRE|OUTDOOR|COMPANY|   MAST|MACRO|   |47001| DU|41.651834|-4.728534|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| ES|15032017|25101|54601|   | 3G|     FIBRE|OUTDOOR|COMPANY|ROOFTOP|MACRO|   |47001| DU|41.651994|-4.724693|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| ES|15032017|25102|54602|   | 4G|     FIBRE|OUTDOOR|COMPANY|ROOFTOP|MICRO|   |47001|  U|41.650912|-4.720648|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| ES|15032017|25103|54603|   | 3G|MICROWAVES|OUTDOOR|COMPANY|ROOFTOP|MACRO|   |47001|  U|41.647312|-4.717118|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+--------+-----+-----+---+---+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----+---+-----+---+---------+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

and the schema is:

```
dfCells.printSchema()
root
 |-- C0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C6: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C9: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C10: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C11: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C12: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C13: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C14: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C15: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C16: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C17: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C18: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C19: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C20: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C21: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C22: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C23: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C24: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C25: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C26: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C27: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C28: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C29: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C30: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C31: string (nullable = true)
```